# bootstrap ui what is the function "then"?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I read the documentation on bootstrap ui(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) .Now I look modal.
I do not understand next lines

```
  modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

What is the function "then"?where I can read about "then".Property result return 
object `Promise {$$state: Object, then: function, catch: function, finally: function}`

Comment: Read about angular `promise` as result is a `promise`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then` is part of the Angular Promises part of the Angular `$q` injector to work with async data that way you dont have to wait responses to continue the execution just use deferred promises this is generally used in services, you can read more about that in the $q documentation of angular [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

a quick example would be this

in service: 'myService'

```
var defered = $q.defer();
$http.post('some/url')
    .success(function(response){ defered.resolve(response); }) // resolve for successfull exec
    .error(function(){ defered.reject("Fail");  });// reject for error responses })
 return defered.promise; // return without waiting for the server response
```

in controller (injecting myService as dependency):

```
myService()
     .then(function(resp){ console.log(resp) }, function(err){ console.warn(err) });
```

where the fisrt function of then is a callback for the successfull promises and the second a callback for errors.